# How to insert the array values in database using for each loop

Tags: codeigniter, model

I have array i want insert into the values in database using codeigniter, i don't know how to insert , i trying but i am not able to get the answer

> My model

**print_r($subjectHandling);**

---

```
 Array
(
    [subjectId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

now i want insert the values in database in this values.

> I am trying like this

```
    foreach($subjectHandling as $key=>$value) {

    $reg_dat = array(
        'statffId'   => '1',
        'subjectId'      => $value,
    );
 $this->db->insert("subject_handling" , $reg_dat);

}
```

I m getting error ** Array to string conversion** , so how do this. i want to insert two roes in databse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$subjectHandling['subjectId'] = array(1, 2); 

$reg_dat = array();
foreach($subjectHandling['subjectId'] as $key => $value) {
 $reg_dat[] = array('staffId'=> 1, 'subjectId' => $value);
}
$this->db->insert_batch('subject_handling', $reg_dat);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data